# Removing a node when an attribute exists

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have the following xml document.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<report>
    <feature tag="Config"/>
    <feature tag="Runtime">
        <feature tag="Output">
            <feature tag="Target">
                    <property name="type" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Html"/>
                    <property name="driver" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Telelogic.Html.Driver"/>
                </feature>
            <feature tag="Target">
                    <property name="type" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Word"/>
                    <property name="driver" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Telelogic.Word.Driver"/>
                </feature>
            <feature tag="Target">
                    <property name="type" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="PDF"/>
                    <property name="driver" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Telelogic.Pdf.Driver"/>
                </feature>
            </feature>
        <feature tag="Log"/>
    </feature>
</report>
```

I want to read all three subnodes "Target" below the "Output" node in order to find out if the value="Html" is present.

If I find the value "Html", this subnode will be unremoved, all others below "Output" I want to remove, that below "Output" only exists one subnode of "Target".

I am using the XDocument class, but I have no success.

```
 Dim doc As New XmlDocument
        Dim nodes As XmlNodeList
        doc.Load(Path)

        nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/report/feature[@tag='Runtime']/feature[@tag='Output']/feature[@tag='Target']")

        For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
            If node.ChildNodes(0).Attributes("value").Value <> "Word" Then
                node.RemoveAll()
            End If
        Next


        doc.Save("c:\temp\test.xml")
```

The result below "Output" is the following, so the "Feature" tags are still remaining.

```html
<feature tag="Output">
      <feature>
      </feature>
      <feature tag="Target">
        <property name="type" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Word">
        </property>
        <property name="driver" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Telelogic.Word.Driver">
        </property>
        <property name="path" type="URI" editable="true" visible="true" required="true" value="">
        </property>
        
      </feature>
      <feature>
      </feature>
      <feature>
      </feature>
      <feature>
      </feature>
    </feature>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what happened when you did it? What was your logic for doing it that way? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, rather than just "I want X, do it for me".

Comment: I edited my question in order to give more informations.

Comment: You need to show the code you tried and explain exactly how it didn't meet your needs. Please spend some time in the Help Center and learn how to ask a proper question, starting with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: a working code snippet was just added.

Comment: @ManfredSinger - I provided a VB answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the data I used

```
    Dim doc As XElement
    ' doc = XElement.Load("your path here")

    'for test use a literal
    doc = <report>
              <feature tag="Config"/>
              <feature tag="Runtime">
                  <feature tag="Output">
                      <feature tag="Target">
                          <property name="type" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Html"/>
                          <property name="driver" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Telelogic.Html.Driver"/>
                      </feature>
                      <feature tag="Target">
                          <property name="type" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Word"/>
                          <property name="driver" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Telelogic.Word.Driver"/>
                      </feature>
                      <feature tag="Target">
                          <property name="type" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="PDF"/>
                          <property name="driver" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Telelogic.Pdf.Driver"/>
                      </feature>
                  </feature>
                  <feature tag="Log"/>
              </feature>
          </report>
```

And the code

```
    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    ie = From el In doc...<feature>
            Where el.@tag = "Output"
             From sel In el...<property>
              Where sel.@value = "Html"
              Select sel.Parent

    If ie.Count = 1 Then
        Dim parent As XElement = ie(0).Parent
        Dim hld As XElement = New XElement(ie(0))
        ie(0).Parent.Nodes.Remove()
        parent.Add(hld)
    End If
```

And the results

```
        'doc after above
        '<report>
        '  <feature tag="Config" />
        '  <feature tag="Runtime">
        '    <feature tag="Output">
        '      <feature tag="Target">
        '        <property name="type" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Html" />
        '        <property name="driver" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="Telelogic.Html.Driver" />
        '      </feature>
        '    </feature>
        '    <feature tag="Log" />
        '  </feature>
        '</report>
```